# why do I get "arthemtic overflow error converting expression to data type int when converting the below code?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create table COSTUMER(
[Costumer ID] int,
[Costumer Phone number] int,
[Costumer Date of Birth] int,
[Costumer Address] text,
[Costumer Name] varchar(40),
[Costumer Buisness if applicable] varchar(40)
);
```

I have created the ABOVE table with its relevant columns and rows and have tried inserting some data into the table by inserting the BELOW code but keep getting Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 "arthemtic overflow error converting expression to data type int" The statement has been terminated error.

I must be doing something wrong but I just don't see it :p

```
INSERT INTO COSTUMER 
      ([Costumer ID],[Costumer Phone number],[Costumer Date of Birth],[Costumer Address]
     ,[Costumer Name],[Costumer Buisness if applicable]) 
VALUES (24,07956485211,27/08/1993,'311 Fullwell avenue','Mohamed Ahmed','TESCO')
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Also your table's `Costumer Date of Birth` is int and you are trying to save a date in that field.

Comment: what data type do you recommend I use for dob? thnks

Comment: your phonenumber exceeds INT.

Comment: Use `DATE` or `DATETIME` if you need to save the time as well.

Comment: Is it `SQL Server`, `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: @Rahul The bracket-quoting says SQL Server, I cleaned up the tags.

Comment: BTW, a phone number is not an integer, not even close. A phone number is really a string (in various different formats depending on the country) that usually contains digit characters. You're also spelling "business" and "customer" wrong, everyone that gets stuck dealing with your table is going to hate you.

Comment: @muistooshort, yes got it from syntax but the comment was meant for OP to clarify this in order to avoid confusion. BTW, your name alias should be `mu is too long` rather :)

Comment: I really want to know if this is a database for professional costume makers ...

Comment: @AHiggins no it isn't. am practising for my second yr at university

Answer (score 3):

Always you appropriate data types for the data you are storing. In your case you should use `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatype for Date of Birth Column.

### Table Definition

```
Create table COSTUMER(
[Costumer ID]                     INT,
[Costumer Phone number]           VARCHAR(100),  --<-- mostly numbers has a leading Zero INT will not respect that
[Costumer Date of Birth]          DATE,          --<--  DATE data type
[Costumer Address]                VARCHAR(MAX),  --<-- avoid using text it has been deprecated in newer versions
[Costumer Name]                   varchar(40),
[Costumer Buisness if applicable] varchar(40)
);
```

### INSERT Statement

```
INSERT INTO COSTUMER 
      ([Costumer ID],[Costumer Phone number],[Costumer Date of Birth],[Costumer Address]
     ,[Costumer Name],[Costumer Buisness if applicable]) 
VALUES (24,'07956485211','19930827','311 Fullwell avenue','Mohamed Ahmed','TESCO')
```

*Note*

Also use more than one column to store Address , Use columns like .....

```
AddressLine1 , AddressLine2, AddressLine3, County/Region, City, PostCode, Country
```

Your current schema violates the basic rules of database normilization.

Comment: But you left them using the wrong type for a phone number, phone numbers are not numbers at all. You also missed the spelling mistakes that will make everyone curse that table's creator for all time.

Comment: Also google the spellings of standard english words, it is spelled `Customer` not `Costumer` makes life easier :)

Comment: I know I have some spelling mistake but that's not the issue thank you for noting tho. this is just practice that's all :))

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks for pointing it out, I thought so but never got around that there are so many things wrong with OP's code :(

Comment: @muistooshort what data type should I use for phone number?

Comment: Use string data type for phone numbers, VARCHAR or NVARCHAR as mostly phone numbers has leading zero, 078998, and some phone number may have hyphen `-` , it is better to use string data type for phone numbers, as I dont think you will ever have to do any mathematical calculations on phone numbers therefore there is no need to use INT data type for it.

Comment: @user3847554 What M.Ali said, similarly for social security numbers, zip codes, and any other strings-that-contain-digits: if you don't perform arithmetic on it then it probably isn't really a number at all. As far as this being practise goes, practise is supposed to help you build good habits (including correct spelling), not bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to insert a phone number as an INT. It should probably be a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR value.

And as user2989408 says, the Date of Birth should be a DATE or DATETIME.

Comment: I have changed the data type for phone number to varchar and dob to date using this code ALTER TABLE table_name
 ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype however am getting Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date now any clues?

Comment: I believe your insert should look like this: `INSERT INTO COSTUMER 
      ([Costumer ID],[Costumer Phone number],[Costumer Date of Birth],[Costumer Address]
     ,[Costumer Name],[Costumer Buisness if applicable]) 
VALUES (24,'07956485211','27/08/1993','311 Fullwell avenue','Mohamed Ahmed','TESCO')`

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic overflow error is because you are trying to stuff data into a column whose datatype is not 'big' enough to hold the data you are trying to put into it.  In other words, the maximum value for the datatype INT is 2,147,483,647 (reference below).

Depending on how the phone number is going to be used, I would store it as a bigint instead of an int.  Bigint will take up 8 bytes of storage (same reference below), whereas for a phone number that is 11 digits (in your post 07956485211) a CHAR datatype will take up 11 bytes and a varchar will take up 13 bytes (reference below)

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx