# Arithmetic overflow error while doing pagination

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pagination

I am trying to get chunk by chunk data but getting below error :

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

**Code :**

```
int chunkSize = 100000;
 int curCount = 1;
 while (true)
 {
    var data = Get("Connectionstring",
        "select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source order by 
         LinkedColumn" + " OFFSET ((" + curCount + " - 1) * " + chunkSize + " 
         ) ROWS FETCH NEXT " + chunkSize + " ROWS ONLY;");

   if (data.Count == 0) break;
   curCount += chunkSize;
 }
```

Above works fine for `first iteration` :

```
select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source order by 
   LinkedColumn OFFSET ((1 - 1) * 100000 ) ROWS FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

But i am getting error for `second iteration` :

```
select Id as LinkedColumn,CompareColumn from Source order by
   LinkedColumn OFFSET ((100001 - 1) * 100000 ) ROWS FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

When i run this above query in sql server management studio i get the same error.

I am not getting whats the problem here.

Answers given on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25144599/why-do-i-get-arthemtic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-int-wh) are related to `insert command`.

Can anybody please help me

Comment: Replace `curCount += chunkSize;` with `curCount++;`, as of now your paging logic is not correct.

Comment: @Evk Oh yes you are right.Thank you so much.Your comment itself is enough to solve the problem :).Actually i have taken reference from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900285/entity-tolist-generates-a-system-outofmemoryexception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `OFFSET` calculation:

```
LinkedColumn OFFSET ((100001 - 1) * 100000 )
```

This would offset by 10,000,000,000 rows, which is hardly what you actually want.

I think it should be

```
LinkedColumn OFFSET ((2 - 1) * 100000 )
```

In each iteration the number should increase by 1 not by `chunkSize`. So probably you are using the `curCount` variable and it should increment (`curCount++`).

Comment: I have taken reference from here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900285/entity-tolist-generates-a-system-outofmemoryexception

Comment: Yes, but that is a Entity Framework implementation, you are writing the SQL manually, which means you have to approach this differently.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and thank you so much for the answer.Appreciated.But the only thing i am not getting that how answer on that question is correct logically?

Comment: Because `Skip` in entity framework basically generated something like `OFFSET( 100000 )`. `Take` then specifies the number for `FETCH NEXT`

Comment: The logic of how the implementation works is different for the two approaches. In your case you generate it by multiplying the number of previous pages by the size of a single page. There they just continuously skip the total number of rows itself.